What is the problem with infinite descending chain?
I'm trying to understand the motivation of well-founded relation.
It is said that well-founded relation is motivated to avoid existence of infinite descending chain.
Could you please tell me what is the problem with infinite descending chain ? It seems to me that the non-existence of infinite descending chain is necessary for induction to work, but really I don't understand why mustn't we have an infinite descending chain ?
Thanks very much for your enlightment!

Not an answer, but: it's not so much that we must not have an infinite descending chain; the Anti-Foundation Axiom (AFA) is another axiom that you can build a set theory off of. But as you said, without Foundation induction becomes substantially harder, and a lot of core set theory proofs come down to induction.

Is your question about the general definition of a well-founded relation? Or about the axiom of foundation in ZFC?

You certainly can have infinitely descending chains.  The integers under the less than relation are an example.  We separate out the well founded relations and orders because they have nice properties that allow us to prove things we want to.  They do make induction easier by having a starting point.

I don't really understand what you mean by "We separate out the well founded relations and orders", can you please ellaborate more on this, if possible ? Many thanks!

We make the definitions of them.  These definitions are useful because we can prove induction will work over the well founded relations and orders.  We don't prohibit orders that have infinite descending chains, we just want a way to talk about orders that don't.
